# Blazor: Which is better inject or cascading value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have Blazor server application in which I have pages organized as follows:

```
- Pages
  - Course
    - Index.razor
    - Manage.razor
    - Add.razor
```

Index page has tab control with 2 tabs (manage, add). Both tabs need to access, let's say, DataService.
Which is better in terms of resource allocation and performance?

1. Inject DataService into both Manage.razor and Add.razor
2. Inject DataService into Index.razor and define cascading value to pass it to Manage.razor and Add.razor

Edit:

In case DataService is singleton then quite clear that inject would be better. I guess if DataService is scoped and then it still be better to inject. What do you think?

Comment: If your DataService is singleton, then it's good to inject it into both components.

Answer (score 0):

**Singleton**: It will create a single instance of the service throughout the application. It does not recommend, apps on the same server share state using singleton services unless extreme care is taken, as this can introduce security vulnerabilities, such as leaking user state across circuits.

**Transient**: It will create a new instance of the service for each component, whenever a component obtains an instance of a Transient service from the service container. It is safer to use.

**Scoped**: It will register a service that behaves like Singleton services. It is preferred for services that should be scoped only to the current user.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this doesn't even broach the same topic as the question. why would you use cascading parameters vs an appstatecontainer?